# How can I know when it's safe to uninstall my i386 packages (on an amd64 system)?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, dependencies, x86, uninstall

I use GNU/Linux Mint 18.1 on an amd64/x86_64 processor. I have a bunch of i386 packages installed - 250 of them to be exact. Up until today I knew I need some/most of them, since I had 32-bit Skype installed. But now I've installed the 64-bit version, so I'm wondering - can I uninstall those i386 packages? Or rather - how can I tell whether I really need any of them or not?

Answer (score 3):

The package manager will usually complain if you try to remove a dependency of another package or program.

Read carefully what it says when it asks if you're sure about removing anything.

Comment: I've expanded on this answer... see below. But +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've specifically installed some 32-bit package (which would also have dependencies etc.) - it's likely that *all* 32-bit/i386 packages can be removed. As @Mioriin suggested, if you try to remove them using `apt-get remove`, you'll get a complaint if anything depends on them.

For caution's sake, first do the following:

```
apt-get install -f
```

in case something is broken and needs fixing. Then execute:

```
dpkg-query -l | grep "^i.* i386   " | less
```

and review the list of relevant packages. See if there's something you recall explicitly installing *specifically as an i386/32-bit package*. If not - proceed to try and remove them with:

```
apt-get remove $(dpkg-query -l | grep "^i.* i386   " | cut -c5- | cut -d\  -f1)
```

(the weird piped commands are for extracting just the package name; I think this can be done better using just `dpkg-query` switches.)

Caveats:

- It's theoretically possible but *extremely* unlikely that some package will have the string " i386    " in its description; unlikely enough to ignore
- If you have packages which are half-installed or in other states other than `ii` (see `man dpkg-query` for details), this might not work for you

Comment: FYI: Package names aren't allowed to contain spaces, so " i386 " can't occur in one. Not just unlikely, it's disallowed. BTW: Might want to consider using `apt-mark` to mark them as autoinstalled, then let autoremove remove ones that aren't needed.

Comment: @derobert: The space is for the listing, which contains the platform and the discription. As for `apt-mark` - what's the benefit in using that, as opposed to just apt-get removing the packages?

Comment: The space is also preventing it from matching, e.g., linux-image-i386 (were such a package to exist). As for apt-mark, the advantage is that apt-get remove will try to additionally remove any packages that depend on the i386 packages, whereas marking the autoinstalled (then using autoremove) will only remove them if nothing declares a dependency on them.

Comment: @derobert: Will edit my answer accordingly (soon).